# How to use Twitter Bootstrap ScrollSpy to execute a function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, dom-events

I would like to load more data after ScrollSpy receives notification. But I don't see how to capture that event and execute a function.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATED**
This trigger has been pushed into the main build now. You can see it in full docs.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

There is an update in the working branch on github that fires an activate callback.

**References**

- https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2482

Once you grab the activate trigger, you can call it like so:

```
$("#nav li").on('activate', function() {
   //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is for Bootstrap 4 (beta 3):**
In general, the usage of the Scrollspy event did not change from Bootstrap 3. As it is stated at the [Events](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#events) section of the Scrollspy documentation, the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event will be fired on the scroll element –the one with `data-spy="scroll"`– whenever a new item becomes activated by the Scrollspy. You can listen to it like that:

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function(event) {
    console.log('activate.bs.scrollspy', event);
})
```

**But!**
It is not documented, that when the Scrollspy is used on the `<body>` element, the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event will be available only on the `window` object.
So, in this rather common case, you can catch the Scrollspy event like so:

```
$(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (event) {
    console.log('activate.bs.scrollspy', event);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 3 you can do it like this ([docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-events))

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
  // do something…
})
```