# ScrollSpy "Activate" event does not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I read this question: [How to use Twitter Bootstrap ScrollSpy to execute a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343715/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-to-execute-a-function), that said to first grab the event, then to add a certain function. First, I'm relatively new to jQuery, so I don't know how to grab an event.

Here is my code:

```
$(".navbar").scrollspy();
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function()
{
    $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
});
$("ul.nav li").on("activate", function()
{
    console.log("ACTIVATED");
});
```

Triggering it manually runs the function, of course, but whatever I try to do, it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, the latest (2.1.0) release of Bootstrap fixes the issue.

See https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3316 and access the working script here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/2.1.0-wip/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js.

Comment: Cool! I'll set it as the correct answer once I can get it to work :)

Comment: I am very sorry for my lateness in accepting the answer. I can confirm it works =)

Answer (score 1):

Your li element is probably missing the dropdown class

```
li.dropdown
```

Otherwise it will not work because he specifically looks for a .dropdown when your element has a parent matching .dropdown-menu ... and in my case it was always true.
Here is the code that does it in bootstrap:

```
      active = $(selector)
      .parent('li')
      .addClass('active')

    if (active.parent('.dropdown-menu'))  {
      active = active.closest('li.dropdown').addClass('active')
    }

    active.trigger('activate')
```