# Using JQuery to trigger an event from Bootstrap Scrollspy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to capture the event of Scrollspy in order to run a function. Scrollspy is working to change the activate link on the navbar. But I am unable to capture the event to use it elsewhere.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="30">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').scrollspy({target: "#navbar", offset: 30});   
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navbar').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function() { 
        console.log('sparkle, sparkle');
    });
});
</script>
```

I understand that in some versions of Bootstrap capturing the event is not possible/working?

Please advise.

Comment: can you provide fiddle.

Comment: Have you cheked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343715/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-to-execute-a-function/10288981?

Comment: I copied that exact code and tried it to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is one of the very few things in Bootstrap 4 that are not well documented –or buggy–. As you have already read at the [Events](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#events) section of the Scrollspy documentation, the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event should be fired on the scroll element –the one with `data-spy="scroll"`–, and handled accordingly:

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function(event) {
    console.log('activate.bs.scrollspy', event);
})
```

However, it is not documented, that when the Scrollspy is used on the `<body>` element, the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event will be available only on the `window` object.
So, you can catch this Scrollspy event like so:

```
$(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function (event) {
    console.log('activate.bs.scrollspy', event);
})
```